# SQL Server 2012 AlwaysOn Availability

Tags: sql-server-2012, availability-groups

Environment:

SQL Server 2012 AlwayOn with 3 Replicas.

Primary ((Manual Failover))

Secondary1 (Manual Failover) -->Read_Intent Only --This is using for some reporting

Secondary2 (Manual Failover)-->Read_Intent Only -- This is using for some reporting

Questions:

In this scenerio how can i implement automatic failover?

If configure automatic failover doesn't it any impact on reporting server connectivity (Read_Intent Only)

Answer (score 0):

Readable/Non-Readable secondary and Failover modes are two different options. One does not affect the other.

The only options that do affect the other is going between automatic/manual and synchronous/async.